# Mock context.Done() in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a HTTP handler that sets a context deadline on each request:

```
func submitHandler(stream chan data) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(r.Context(), 5*time.Second)
        defer cancel()

        // read request body, etc.

        select {
        case stream <- req:
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
        case <-ctx.Done():
            err := ctx.Err()
            if err == context.DeadlineExceeded {
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusRequestTimeout)
            }
            log.Printf("context done: %v", err)
        }
    }
}
```

I am easily able to test the `http.StatusNoContent` header, but I am unsure about how to test the `<-ctx.Done()` case in the select statement.

In my test case I have built a mock `context.Context` and passed it to the `req.WithContext()` method on my mock `http.Request`, however, the status code returned is always `http.StatusNoContent` which leads me to believe the `select` statement is always falling into the first case in my test.

```
type mockContext struct{}

func (ctx mockContext) Deadline() (deadline time.Time, ok bool) {
    return deadline, ok
}

func (ctx mockContext) Done() <-chan struct{} {
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    close(ch)
    return ch
}

func (ctx mockContext) Err() error {
    return context.DeadlineExceeded
}

func (ctx mockContext) Value(key interface{}) interface{} {
    return nil
}

func TestHandler(t *testing.T) {
    stream := make(chan data, 1)
    defer close(stream)

    handler := submitHandler(stream)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/submit", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    req = req.WithContext(mockContext{})

    rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler.ServeHTTP(rec, req)

    if rec.Code != http.StatusRequestTimeout {
        t.Errorf("expected status code: %d, got: %d", http.StatusRequestTimeout, rec.Code)
    }
}
```

How could I mock the context deadline has exceeded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, after much trial and error I figured out what I was doing wrong. Instead of trying to create a mock `context.Context`, I created a new one with an expired deadline and immediately called the returned `cancelFunc`. I then passed this to `req.WithContext()` and now it works like a charm!

```
func TestHandler(t *testing.T) {
    stream := make(chan data, 1)
    defer close(stream)

    handler := submitHandler(stream)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/submit", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    stream <- data{}
    ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(req.Context(), time.Now().Add(-7*time.Hour))
    cancel()
    req = req.WithContext(ctx)

    rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler.ServeHTTP(rec, req)

    if rec.Code != http.StatusRequestTimeout {
        t.Errorf("expected status code: %d, got: %d", http.StatusRequestTimeout, rec.Code)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `mockContext` type's `Done` method will never return done, because nothing ever writes to the channel, so your goroutine sits around forever before it closes the channel, thus triggering the Done state.  If you want it to immediately report done, try this:

```
func (ctx mockContext) Done() <-chan struct{} {
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    close(ch)
    return ch
}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but it still doesn't seem to work.